# How can I hide my source code in HuggingFace spaces?

Tags: python, huggingface

I've been trying to figure out how to hide my source code in public HuggingFace spaces, but I wasn't able to find a solution for this. Here is what I've read and tried:

1. Using Google Actions to rely on tokens, but the code is synced of course to the HuggingFace space, so it is visible.
2. In the documentation it is said that Git LFS can be used to make the models hidden, but this cannot be applied to source code.
3. I've also read about using secrets, but this applies to API keys, not app functions.

Note: I've searched for a more relevant community to post this question and already asked the question in HuggingFace community, but no help yet.

Comment: This question is way too broad for StackOverflow since it will in all likelihood lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: It's not opinion-based. There should be a solution for such a problem. It's clear that a single solution will be enough. If you've read my note, you will notice that I wrote that there is no better community to the problem. For example, I can't post it in the Data Science or AI communities because they are irrelevant.

Comment: By your own research, you indicate there exist multiple approaches to a solution, thus what other than differing opinions would you expect in response.

Comment: What I wrote are solutions found to hide API secrets, large dataset files, and model files, not source code or functions.

Comment: What is HuggingFace? The tag does not have a description. How is this question related to Python?

Comment: HuggingFace is a platform that is used by machine learning engineers to train and deploy machine learning models. The main programming language that is supported for model training and deployment is python. It includes many pre-trained models provided by Meta, Nividia, and many more companies. Also, it is worth 2bn$ and there is some news that Google may buy it soon.